# Using $(document).ready with a html inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can i use jquery **function $(document).ready(function() {});** using a javascript variable containing html recovered from a **$("#tableId").prop("outerHTML");** function as parameter? Just like down bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var tempHtml = $("#tabelaOriginal-1").prop("outerHTML");
$(tempHtml).ready(function() {
    $("someDivId").css( "background-color", "yellow" );
});
```

The tempHtml will suffer changes? Caused by the .css function call. In short, i need recover html data from a div and do some alterations and build a modal with this alterations without make any alterations in the original div. So i'm trying to use the inner call of jquery .ready function passing the outerHTML as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method for what you are trying to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var clone = $("#tabelaOriginal-1").clone();
   clone.css( "background-color", "yellow" );
   //Now use the cloned object in a modal or do whatever you want.
});
```

I strongly recommend you to go through `clone` documentation to understand it's optional features.

Comment: Well, thats worked fine to build the modal thank you. But now i have another question. Can i access inners ids in tempHtml? I need to change the background color in a specifically div inside tempHtml.

Comment: Yes you can find any dom element inside the cloned object using any selector.

Comment: I used tempHtml.find("#row1-Name").css( "background-color", "yellow" ); and works very fine. Well played sir. Thank you!